# session not storing on browser in Django

Tags: python, django, reactjs

I'm trying to build an app using `React TSX` for the front-end side and `Django` for the back-end side. I want to store the session on the browser using the `SESSION_ENGINE=django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies`. So, I want to store the sessions in a similar way of how `PHP` or `Apache` stores its sessions. I have tried a lot of ways but I am still not able to store the sessions, I keep getting the output `SESSION IS NOW SET` from my code. Any help will be great. Thanks

`login.tsx`

```
import Cookies from "js-cookie";
import axios, { AxiosResponse, AxiosError } from "axios";

..........
..........

axios.request({
    url: "login/",
    baseURL: "http://localhost:8000/",
    method: "POST",
    data: data,
    timeout: 15000,
    withCredentials: true,
    headers: { "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest", "X-CSRFToken": Cookies.get("csrftoken") },
    validateStatus: () => true
}).then((res: AxiosResponse): void => {
    console.log(res.data);
});
```

`login.py`

```
from django.http import HttpResponse

def get(req):
    req.session.modified = True

    if req.session.get("user_id", False):
        return HttpResponse("EXISTS: " + req.session.get("user_id"))   <-- THIS OUTPUT IS NEVER BEING RETRIEVED
    else:
        req.session["user_id"] = "USER-ID"
        req.session.save()
        return HttpResponse("SESSION IS NOW SET")   <-- THIS IS THE ONLY OUTPUT BEING RETRIEVED
```

`settings.py`

```
..........
..........

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders'
]

SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies"
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = "sessioninfo"

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [ "http://localhost:5000" ]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = ["GET","POST"]
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [ "accept", "accept-encoding", "authorization", "content-type", "dnt", "origin", "user-agent", "x-csrftoken", "x-requested-with" ]

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True

..........
..........
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. All I had to do was my edit my `settings.py` to this:

```
..........
..........

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'corsheaders'
]

SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies"
SESSION_COOKIE_NAME = "user_session"
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = [ "http://localhost:5000" ]
CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True
CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS = True
CORS_ALLOW_METHODS = ["GET","POST"]
CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS = [ "accept", "accept-encoding", "authorization", "content-type", "dnt", "origin", "user-agent", "x-csrftoken", "x-requested-with" ]

CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True

..........
..........
```